# Is it possible to define more than 9 shortcuts for notebook cell styles?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, stylesheet

You can define shortcuts for notebook cell styles in the stylesheet editor, by adding `MenuCommandKey->"7",` etc. to the style definition. That is, you can define <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> to set/create a cell with one style, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> a different style, ..., through <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>.

From the documentation in Mathematica 8 for `MenuCommandKey` for styles:

> Acceptable values include None and "1" through "9".

So it appears that there are only 9 possible shortcuts. But there are more than 9 styles I commonly use. Is it possible to define additional such shortcuts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose most letters I believe. I have alt+M for MathCaption for example.

If you have v8, what I found most useful was to group all the title-subtitle-..., section-subsection-..., item-subitem-..., itemNumbered..., sectionNumbered..., Input-code-whatever, in a single style and tab or backspace to move to the next-previous style in the hierarchy with the cell option StyleKeyMapping

Comment: Seems to be undocumented, but it works.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the shift key, too. So, in one stylesheet I have, I have defined `MenuCommandKey -> "5"` for `Item` and `MenuCommandKey -> "%"` for `SubItem`.